# Продолжение работы после отправки PullRequest

Tags: git, pull-request

Создал `PullRequest`. Могу ли я создать новую ветку и продолжить в ней работать, не дожидаясь слияния?

Comment: А вы пробовали?

Comment: Вам наверное что-то мешает попробовать. Так вот и опишите свои опасения. Если попробовали но не получилось - тогда вопрос должен быть такого вида: "КАК я могу ...", Если получилось, но не так как хотелось - тогда опишите что хотелось и что получилось.  А то Вам придется по каждому шагу спрашивать. Но и ответы будете получать типа "да" или "нет".

Comment: Как я могу продолжить работу в  новой ветке после отправки PullRequest и не дожидаясь слияния старой ветки с мастер?